# stringFromDate always NIL

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, nsdate

I know this is a repetitive question, but after searching for many similar questions on stackoverflow and google, none of the solutions worked for me.

I am tring to convert date which I receive from DB to string format to display in iPhone app.

I am converting date to string in following manner, but `[dateFormat stringFromDate:beginDate]` always return nil.

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MMM dd hh:mm a"];
NSString *dateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:beginDate];
NSLog(@"date: %@", dateString);
[dateFormat release];
```

The server NSDate received is of following format:

```
2012-05-23 13:06:51.394+1000
```

and I want it to

```
May 25 13:06 PM
```

Comment: what are you getting when you NSLog beginDate?

Comment: Printing description of dateFormat:
<NSDateFormatter: 0x8025970>
Printing description of beginDate:
2012-05-23 13:06:51.394+1000

Comment: Just used your code with `[NSDate date]` instead of beginDate; Got this `2012-05-23 09:08:41.993 Training[293:207] date: May 23 09:08 AM`, maybe check your beginDate?

Comment: With [NSDate date ], the code works but I want to use beginDate which is coming from DB. What needs to be done in that casE?

Comment: What data type does the DB return?

Comment: NSDate *beginDate = [arr_data objectAtIndex:1]; where arr_data has NSString object

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to convert your beginDate string to an actual NSDate first, and then do it:

```
NSString *beginDateString  = [arr_data objectAtIndex:1];
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"];
NSDate *beginDate = [formatter dateFromString:beginDateString];

[formatter setDateFormat:@"MMM dd hh:mm a"];
NSString *dateString = [formatter stringFromDate:beginDate];
NSLog(@"date: %@", dateString);
```

Note that you say in your question that you want it to output `May 25 13:06 PM` but it will actually output `May 25 01:06 PM`.  (13:06 would be using 24 hour time instead of 12 hour time and wouldn't need the am/pm.)

Answer (score 5):

What is the type of beginDate? If it is NSString, then convert it to NSDate first, by using `dateFromString` method of NSDateFormatter.

```
NSString *beginDate = @"2012-05-23 13:06:51.394+1000";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

// Set the format of the dateFormatter to the date format of the server
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:MM:ss.SSSZ";
// Convert the NSString to NSDate
NSDate* date = [dateFormatter dateFromString: beginDate];

// Set the format of dateFormatter to your own format
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"MMM dd hh:mm a";
// Convert NSDate to your own format of date
beginDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate: date];
```

Comment: NSString *beginDate = [arr_data objectAtIndex:1];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MM dd HH:MM a"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:beginDate];  
        
        // Convert date object to desired output format
        [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MM dd HH:MM a"];
        beginDate = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date];  
        [dateFormat release];   Tried this but still NIL

Comment: Its still nil : tried new update: Printing description of date:
<nil>
Printing description of beginDate:
<nil>

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong in above code, it works fine with current date. Just replace

```
NSString *dateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:beginDate];
```

by

```
NSString *dateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
```

and will work.

It seems that there is problem with your `beginDate`.

Comment: But beginDate is coming from DB, and NSDate date gives me today's date. What to do in case of beginDate?

Comment: is beginDate is a NSString object ?

Comment: NSDate *beginDate = [arr_data objectAtIndex:1];  where arr_data had all data from db

Comment: Unless you are storing it as an NSDate (not likely, but possible, set a breakpoint to check) you will have to convert from the original string to a real NSDate first.

Comment: and what are you adding in arr_data, sting objects ?

Comment: this nsstring object is causing the issue... you are direct using a NSString object as NSDate, which is wrong...use lnafziger answer to covert string to date then use this date object to get formatted string.

Answer (score 0):

May be your beginDate's format is like "2013-09-29 14:57:48.0",but the dataFormate is

```
[dFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"]
```

change to "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.0" will be OK

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `setDateFormat` before calling `stringFromDate`

```
NSDateFormatter * dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm dd/MM/yyyy"];
NSString * dateString =[dateFormatter stringFromDate:someDate];
```