# date value is return nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

one value added into NSMutableArray with dictionary 
SelectedDate = "2016-08-12";

I am trying to fetch the date from my MutableArray,

```
   NSDate *dateFromTable = [[Array valueForKey:@"SelectedDate"] objectAtIndex:0];
            NSDateFormatter *dateformate=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
            [dateformate setDateFormat:@"dd"];
       NSString   *dateValue = [dateformate stringFromDate:dateFromTable];
```

dateValue is always return nil, 
No idea what I did wrong.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10713024/stringfromdate-always-nil

Comment: what is that line `NSDate *dateFromTable = [[Array valueForKey:@"SelectedDate"] objectAtIndex:0];`? __triple checked that line's sanity?__ because that probably does not present an `NSDate` instance at all, but it is most likely an `NSString` – it won't cause crash but it falls back to `nil` when you intend to format it, it does not matter how hard you'd try; therefore you'd need to convert the value to an `NSDate` instance first.

Comment: Your question implies that you wish to extract the day portion of a date string. But your code is written as if you are starting with an `NSDate`, not an `NSString`.

Comment: KkMIVV check my answer

Answer (score 0):

Adjust this to your code:

```
NSArray *array = @[@"2016-08-12"]; // array with dates in string format
NSString *dateFromTable = array.firstObject; // get first element
NSDateFormatter *dateformater =[NSDateFormatter new];
[dateformater setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
NSDate *date = [dateformater dateFromString:dateFromTable]; // get date from string
NSLog(@"%@", date); // 2016-08-12 22:00:00 +0000
[dateformater setDateFormat:@"dd"];
NSString *dateValue = [dateformater stringFromDate:date]; // get string from date
NSLog(@"%@", dateValue); // 12
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the date from array to string and convert to date

```
NSString *dateFromTable = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[Array valueForKey:@"SelectedDate"] objectAtIndex:0]];
NSDateFormatter *dateformate=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateformate setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
NSDate   *dateValue = [dateformate dateFromString:dateFromTable];
```

Then If you want to get the date to string follow below steps

```
[dateformat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"]; //Whatever you want to change the date format change here
NSString *strDateValue = [dateformater stringFromDate:dateValue];
```